# Does adjacency imply intersection?

Tags: geometry

If two rectangles are adjacent to one another (that is, they are butted up against one another and share one side with the other), does that also mean that they are intersected?

In addition to an answer & simple explanation, can anyone point me to a formal math proof for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two rectangles abutting at a side (sharing a side) indeed means they intersect, and the intersection consists of all the infinitely many points that lie on that common side.

This is by definition, not proof.

(The set of all points lying on rectangle 1) $\cap$  (the set of all points lying on rectangle 2) = the set of all points the rectangles share in common, (all points that belong to both rectangle 1 and rectangle 2), and this is by the definition of intersection of points (or of lines).

That intersection is precisely the line segment (side) at which your rectangles are joined.

Comment: Awesome - thanks @amWhy (+1) - I'm actually having an argument with a co-worker over this, and was hoping to be able to point him to a proof. What you're saying makes total sense (and helped answer the first part of my question), but I could really use some definitive source that qualifies what you're saying. Is there a theorem I could reference? Thanks again!

Comment: The reason we speak of "by definition" in Euclidean Geometry, is that it is founded on a set of "what we take to be true" (the most fundamental "notions" we cannot rationally deny), a set of axioms and definitions, and from these, theorems, etc. So things like the notion of a point, and then definitions of a line segment  defined in terms of points, and a line in terms of a line segment, etc. continue to build an edifice in which we speak of "shapes" which are defined, etc. You might want to have a look at **Euclid's Elements**.

Comment: Thanks again so much @amWhy! (+1 again). I **hate** to be a pest here, but if there are any theorems you can cite, Wikipedia articles, etc., that would help me out *enormously*, and I'd happily give you the "green check" for best answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Just Google "Euclid's Elements": It's available and freely accessible at many locations, even down-loadable (freely). Also, Wikipedia will most definitely have an entry for "Euclid's Elements", and also has some of the basic notions/axioms/definitions.

Comment: Thanks again @amWhy - I found a copy [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/euclid/elements.pdf). It seems that it is divided up into 13 "Books" over 500 pages (!). Any idea what book I might be able to find these axioms/definitions in? Thanks again!

Comment: Not off the bat - so sorry about that. I'd thumb through my own copy, but I am starving and need my dinner!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV! +1